# I want to have separate Keypad passcodes to light up an RGB and run a DC Motor in one code. 6113 for RGB and 4613 for the DC Motor

Tags: arduino-uno

```
#include <Keypad.h>

const int ROW_NUM = 4; //four rows
const int COLUMN_NUM = 3; //three columns

const int PIN_RED = 2;
const int PIN_GREEN = 3;
const int PIN_BLUE = 4;

const int MOTOR_PIN1 = 5;
const int MOTOR_PIN2 = 13;

char keys[ROW_NUM][COLUMN_NUM] = {
  {'1','2','3'},
  {'4','5','6'},
  {'7','8','9'},
  {'*','0','#'}
};

byte pin_rows[ROW_NUM] = {12, 11, 10, 9};
byte pin_column[COLUMN_NUM] = {8, 7, 6}; 

Keypad keypad = Keypad( makeKeymap(keys), pin_rows, pin_column, ROW_NUM, COLUMN_NUM );

const String password_1 = "6113"; 
const String password_2 = "4613"; 
String input_password;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);
  input_password.reserve(32); // maximum input characters is 33, change if needed
}


void loop(){
     loop_RGB();
     loop_DCMOTOR();
}

void loop_RGB(){
  char key = keypad.getKey();

  if (key){
    Serial.println(key);

    if(key == '*') {
      input_password = ""; // reset the input password
    } else if(key == '#') {
      if(input_password == password_1) {
        Serial.println("password is correct");

  analogWrite(PIN_RED,   255);
  analogWrite(PIN_GREEN, 0);
  analogWrite(PIN_BLUE,  0);

  delay(1000); // keep the color 1 second

  analogWrite(PIN_RED,   0);
  analogWrite(PIN_GREEN, 255);
  analogWrite(PIN_BLUE,  0);

  delay(1000); // keep the color 1 second

  analogWrite(PIN_RED,   0);
  analogWrite(PIN_GREEN, 0);
  analogWrite(PIN_BLUE,  255);

  delay(1000);        
      } else {
        Serial.println("password is incorrect, try again");
      }

      input_password = ""; // reset the input password
    } else {
      input_password += key; // append new character to input password string
    }
  }
}


void loop_DCMOTOR(){
  char key = keypad.getKey();

  if (key){
    Serial.println(key);

    if(key == '*') {
      input_password = ""; // reset the input password
    } else if(key == '#') {
      if(input_password == password_2) {
        Serial.println("password is correct");

     digitalWrite(MOTOR_PIN1, HIGH); 
     digitalWrite(MOTOR_PIN2, LOW); 
     delay (3000);
     
      } else {
        Serial.println("password is incorrect, try again");
      }

      input_password = ""; // reset the input password
    } else {
      input_password += key; // append new character to input password string
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: the keyboard code should not be part of the LED code, or part of the motor code ... the keyboard code should be completely separate ... it should simply update the value of a variable depending on which code is entered ... the motor code and led code should simply monitor the value of the variable and run accordingly

Answer (score 2):

In this program, the functions `loop_RGB()` and `loop_DCMOTOR()` are
taking turns to try to read the password. If you hit `#` after typing
the password for the LED, and `loop_DCMOTOR()` happens to to read your
key press, it will tell you the password is wrong, and reset what you
have typed.

As already stated in a comment and an answer, the solution is to read
the keypad in only one place. You could write a dedicated function for
this, but I would instead just put this code in loop:

```cpp
void loop() {
    char key = keypad.getKey();

    if (key) {
        Serial.print("key pressed: ");
        Serial.println(key);
        if (key == '*') {  // '*' means reset the input
            input_password = "";
        } else if (key == '#') {  // '#' means validate the input
            if (input_password == password_1) {
                Serial.println("Corect RGB LED password.");
                actuate_LED();
            } else if (input_password == password_2) {
                Serial.println("Corect motor password.");
                actuate_motor();
            } else {
                Serial.println("Incorrect password.");
            }
            input_password = "";  // reset the input
        } else {
            input_password += key;  // append new character
        }
    }
}
```

Here, `actuate_LED()` and `actuate_motor()` are supposed to be small
functions that do the device actuation and nothing more. They do not
concern themselves with the keypad or a password.

Answer (score -1):

write 3 functions, one to receive the password, one to run the DC motor, one to drive the LED. Now in the function to receive the password use an array of 4 bytes to store the password and the 'x' button to clear the array. The function should run a for loop to receive all the 4 digits and the "x" key should break the loop and clear out the array.
You can write the RGB and Motor driver function as per your needs.
In the main loop, you should receive the password and then process this password to run the RGB or motor using a if-else condition.
For any further query feel free to clarify.